# Deleted column is still appearing in new & edit forms of a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, column, list-form, edit-form

The already deleted column is still appearing in the *New* and *Edit* Forms of a list.

We have already deleted the column but still it appears.

Comment: Can you share screen shot?

Comment: Whether the default NewForm and EditForm of the list or the custom NewForm and EditForm of the list?

Comment: Can you share the screen shot? Which version of SharePoint you are using